# how to access validation result on blur in redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I want to stop anything onblur function if validation fails. i am not sure how to do this

here is the field

```
<Field
                                    label="Demand Ref"
                                    name="demand_ref"
                                    component={this.renderTextField}
                                    type="text"
                                    onBlur={e => this.onAfterSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
                                    onFocus={e => this.onBeforeSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
                                    validate={[validateDemandRef]}
                                    maxlength="15"
                                />
```

if `validate` fails i don't want anything in `onBlur` to run. how can i do this?

UPDATE

If i am using `validate={[validateDemandRef]}` what do i pass into `...some validation`

UPDATE 2

how woudl this look if it is a class `const MyComponent = ({ handleSubmit, valid }) => (`. `MyComponent` is a class

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isValid` or `isInvalid` selectors (https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { reduxForm, isValid } from 'redux-form';

const MyComponent = ({ handleSubmit, valid }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field
      label="Demand Ref"
      name="demand_ref"
      component={this.renderTextField}
      type="text"
      onBlur={valid && e => this.onAfterSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
      onFocus={e => this.onBeforeSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
      validate={[validateDemandRef]}
      maxlength="15"
    />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
);

const FORM_NAME = 'my-form';

export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: FORM_NAME,
  }),
  connect(state => ({
    valid: isValid(FORM_NAME)(state),  // also there is an isInvalid selector
  })),
)(MyComponent);
```

**For stateful component implementation**

```js
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { reduxForm, isValid } from 'redux-form';

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, valid } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Field
          label="Demand Ref"
          name="demand_ref"
          component={this.renderTextField}
          type="text"
          onBlur={valid && e => this.onAfterSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
          onFocus={e => this.onBeforeSaveCell(e, 'demand_ref')}
          validate={[validateDemandRef]}
          maxlength="15"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const FORM_NAME = 'my-form';

export default compose(
  reduxForm({
    form: FORM_NAME,
  }),
  connect(state => ({
    valid: isValid(FORM_NAME)(state),  // also there is an isInvalid selector
  })),
)(MyComponent);
```

Comment: i added a note on the question

Comment: Never mind. If you are using field-level validation, just skip the form-level one. I posted it just for example.

Comment: Updated the answer to be not confusing.

Comment: It will be the same. Added the implementation for the stateful component. Check the React docs for the stateless functions and Components.